# Select one row from multiple groups in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a rowset that consists of something like this:

```
id1           id2          value
--------------------------------
  1             1             50
  2             1             60
  3             1             70
  4             1             40
  5             1             53
 15             2             10
 16             2             19
 17             2             17
 18             2             13
 20             2             14
 40             3             32
 40             3             34
 44             3             54
 40             3             67
 43             3             80
```

From this rowset, I want the id1 values per id2 group with maximum value. Something like this:

```
id1           id2          value
--------------------------------
  3             1             70
 16             2             19
 43             3             80
```

I only care about id1 and id2, the value column is just for illustrative purposes.

The query must run on MariaDB 5.5. I've been thinking about this, but have yet to find a descent (and performant...) SQL query.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM sometable t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
       id2,
       MAX(`value`) val
    FROM sometable
    GROUP BY id2
) t2
ON t.`value` = t2.val
   AND t.id2 = t2.id2
```

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value = (select max(t2.value)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.id2 = t.id2
                );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(id2, value)`.